# React native app saying Build failed on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

This project was created for react-native expo and later it is converted into react-native CLI.
Now some of the library doesn't get supported on Xcode and I keep getting build failed.

#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
^
1 error generated.
homeyapp/node_modules/expo-font/ios/EXFont/EXFontScaler.m:3:
homeyapp/node_modules/expo-font/ios/EXFont/EXFontScaler.h:4:9: fatal error: could not build module 'ExpoModulesCore'
#import <ExpoModulesCore/EXFontScalerInterface.h>

```
2 errors generated.

How do I resolve this? Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here on v0.63.4. The only change I've made to the last time it could run was adding Crashlytics and configuring the `AppDelegate.m` file.

Comment: After adding files you may want to update your pod and re link your files ‘npx react-native config —verbose’ in the root of your project. If that doesn’t work try performing a clean like this:  ‘npx react-native clean —verbose && yarn install && npx react-native config —verbose && cd ./ios && pod install && cd ..’

Answer (score 0):

After adding files you may want to update your pod and re link your files ‘npx react-native config —verbose’ in the root of your project. If that doesn’t work try performing a clean like this:  ‘npx react-native clean —verbose && yarn install && npx react-native config —verbose && cd ./ios && pod install && cd ..’